# dcast fails to cast character column when the data size is large

Tags: r, dcast

I'm using the `dcast` function in the  `library(reshape2)` package to cast a simple table of three columns

`````
df = data.table(id  = 1:1e6, 
             var = c('continent','subcontinent',...), 
             val = c('America','Caribbean',...)````
`````

by `dcast(df, id ~ var, value.var ='val')` and it automatically converts the value to the count, i.e.

```
id     continent   subcontinent
 1     1           1
 2     1           1
```

However, if I reduce the size to 10000 rows, it correctly outputs

```
id     continent   subcontinent
 1     America     Caribbean
 2     Europe      West Europe
```

Is this a bug or I need to change the code somehow? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the output --- if you use dcast on the example df above your column headers will be subcontinent, continent etc.

Comment: You are definitely right, @RK1，the output is not correct. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the output.

Comment: Cool, makes a lot more sense now :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not the size of the dataset itself but the occurrence of duplicate entries in the full dataset. By picking smaller subsets from the full dataset there is a chance that no duplicates are included.

`help("dcast", "data.table")` says:

> When variable combinations in `formula` doesn't identify a unique value in a cell, `fun.aggregate` will have to be specified, which defaults to `length` if unspecified.

#### How to find duplicates in the full dataset

All occurrences of duplicates can be identified by

```
cols <- c("id", "var")
df[duplicated(df, by = cols) | duplicated(df, by = cols, fromLast = TRUE)][
  order(id)]
```

> ```
>    id          var           val
> 1:  1 subcontinent     Caribbean
> 2:  1 subcontinent South America
> ```

Note that we are looking for duplicates in `id` and `var` as these two form the *cells*, i.e., rows and columns, of the reshaped result.

#### Why `unique()` doesn't work

NB: This is the explanation why simply taking `unique(df)` will not work:

```
unique(df)
```

> ```
>    id          var           val
> 1:  1    continent       America
> 2:  1 subcontinent     Caribbean
> 3:  2    continent        Europe
> 4:  2 subcontinent   West Europe
> 5:  1 subcontinent South America
> ```

does not remove any rows. Consequently,

```
dcast(unique(df), id ~ var, value.var = "val")
```

> ```
> Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
>    id continent subcontinent
> 1:  1         1            2
> 2:  2         1            1
> ```

Whereas

```
unique(df, by = cols)
```

> ```
>    id          var         val
> 1:  1    continent     America
> 2:  1 subcontinent   Caribbean
> 3:  2    continent      Europe
> 4:  2 subcontinent West Europe
> ```

has removed the duplicate `var` for `id == 1L`. Consequently,

```
dcast(unique(df, by = cols), id ~ var, value.var = "val")
```

> ```
>    id continent subcontinent
> 1:  1   America    Caribbean
> 2:  2    Europe  West Europe
> ```

#### How to find the row numbers of duplicated rows

The OP has reported that the issue appears only with the full dataset but not with a subset of the first `1e5` rows.

The row indices of the duplicate entries can be found by

```
which(duplicated(df, by = cols))
```

which returns `5` for the sample dataset. For OP's full dataset, I suspect that

```
min(which(duplicated(df, by = cols))) > 1e5
```

is true, i.e., there are no duplicates within the first 1e5 rows.

#### How to create character columns even in case of duplicate entries

[OP's own approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52357713/3817004) using `fun.aggregate = function(x) paste(x[1L])` as well as applying `unique()` on `df` just aim at removing any disturbing duplicates. The duplicates will be silently dropped.

Alternatively, `toString()` can be used as aggregation function which shows the duplicate entries:

```
dcast(df, id ~ var, toString, value.var = "val")
```

> ```
>    id continent             subcontinent
> 1:  1   America Caribbean, South America
> 2:  2    Europe              West Europe
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(
  id  = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L),
  var = c("continent", "subcontinent", "continent", "subcontinent", "subcontinent"),
  val = c("America", "Caribbean", "Europe", "West Europe", "South America")
)

df
```

> ```
>    id          var           val
> 1:  1    continent       America
> 2:  1 subcontinent     Caribbean
> 3:  2    continent        Europe
> 4:  2 subcontinent   West Europe
> 5:  1 subcontinent South America
> ```

Comment: Thanks, @Uwe, this is indeed a duplicate issue. Problem solved now.

Comment: Genius! Great explanation too :)

Answer (score 1):

**This is likely caused by duplicate entries.**

So it is possible in your subset you inadvertently remove duplicate row entries.

**Output using a DF with duplicate entries**

```
df = data.table(id  = c(1,2,3,4,2), 
                var = c('continent','subcontinent','continent','continent','subcontinent'), 
                val = c('America','Caribbean','Africa','Europe','Caribbean'))

dcast(df, id ~ var, value.var ='val')

Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
   id continent subcontinent
1:  1         1            0
2:  2         0            2
3:  3         1            0
4:  4         1            0
```

> Try unique()

If the duplicates aren't of importance might be worth:

```
dcast(unique(df), id ~ var, value.var ='val')

   id continent subcontinent
1:  1   America           NA
2:  2        NA    Caribbean
3:  3    Africa           NA
4:  4    Europe           NA
```

Comment: Thanks, @RK1, I tried unique() as well and it doesn't fix the issue. However, if I reduce the size from 1e6 to 1e5, it works again

Comment: Hmm interesting --- can you try dcast df[1e5:1e6,] , see if that produces the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick fix to this problem by including the aggregate function. It works now but I'm still not sure why `dcast` behave different for different size of data.

`dcast(df, id ~ var, value.var ='val', fun.aggregate =function(x) paste(x[1])`